# bind value at index 2 is null

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have two activities. Sending data from one activity to another through intent. Then I'm calling a function from database to show all the record of that particular row.
Here `feeder_no` and `date` are composite primary key.
I don't have null value for any record still there's a error null value at index 2.

> This is function definition in database:

```
//show feeder details date wise
public Cursor showFeederDateWiseDetails(int feeder_no, String date) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from " + TABLE_FEEDER_DETAILS + " where feeder_no = ? and date = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(feeder_no), date});
    while (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        if(cursor.getCount()>0)
            return cursor;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Function call**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
try {
    feeder_no = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("feeder_no"));
}catch (NumberFormatException e){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
String date = intent.getStringExtra("date");
Cursor answer = myDB.showFeederDateWiseDetails(feeder_no, date);
while (answer.moveToNext()) {
    t1.setText(answer.getString(1));
    t2.setText(answer.getString(2));
    t3.setText(answer.getString(3));
}
```

> This is how I am getting value of date and feeder no from one acitivity

```
private void openFeederDetailsPage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FeederDetailsDateWise.class);
    intent.putExtra("feeder_no", getFeederNo);
    intent.putExtra("date", getDate);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: How many columns does your query return?

Comment: It returns six columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your code.

Since `feeder_no` and `date` are composite primary key then you should expect that the query will return at most 1 row, so there is no need for a loop after you get the cursor.
A simple call to `cursor.moveToFirst()` is enough to check if the cursor returned a row.

Then when you get the cursor with the call to `showFeederDateWiseDetails()` you must check only if it is `null`.
If it is not, then you get the column values (there is no need to call `moveToFirst()` again, it is already done previously).

Finally, get the column values not directly by their index (which is not safe in a query which returns many columns) but by `getColumnIndex()` using their name.
You should know that the index 1 you use in `t1.setText(answer.getString(1));` returns the value of the 2nd column since the index is `0` based.

Also, you should move the code that calls `showFeederDateWiseDetails()` inside the `try...catch` block:

```
public Cursor showFeederDateWiseDetails(int feeder_no, String date) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from " + TABLE_FEEDER_DETAILS + " where feeder_no = ? and date = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(feeder_no), date});
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) return cursor;
    return null;
}
.........................................................................
Intent intent = getIntent();
try {
    feeder_no = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("feeder_no"));
    String date = intent.getStringExtra("date");
    Cursor answer = myDB.showFeederDateWiseDetails(feeder_no, date);
    if (answer != null) {
        t1.setText(answer.getString(answer.getColumnIndex("column1")));
        t2.setText(answer.getString(answer.getColumnIndex("column2")));
        t3.setText(answer.getString(answer.getColumnIndex("column3")));
    }
    answer.close();
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Change `column1`, `column2` and `column3` to the actual names of the columns returned by your query.

Comment: There's still error. The values of columns are not shown in textview

Comment: @Sum does the app crash or you just don't get the values in the textviews?

Comment: the app crashed

Comment: @Sum what is the message in the error log?

Comment: @Sum if you see the toast message this means that the app did not crash but you have an incorrect number that you tried to convert to an integer. If the app crashes there is an error log at the bottom of the screen in Android Studio that you can read.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234609/discussion-between-sum-and-forpas).